# default directory of domino designer project

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I want to access directory of domino designer project by java agent to make  report from database ,I want to save this report file in agent directory I try this code

```
           File file = new File("Local/file.txt");
```

but it doesn't work.Can any one help me please?

Comment: You need to give more details than just "it doesn't work". Tell us *how* it doesn't work. Does it throw an error? Does it not create a file? Does it create a file, but in an unexpected place? What does happen??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Domino Designer for Eclipse creates the Local directory for each project in a location you can figure out, but it probably is NOT the place to create a report file. The Local directory is in the `Notes/Data/Workspace/<servername>/<dbpath>/Local`. You would be better to use a directory below the `Notes/Data` directory which you can find using  `NotesSession.getEnviromentString("Directory", true)`